# C# \n, \r\n or Environment.NewLine

Tags: c#, wpf, newline, lf

As the heading implies, would I be best to use `\n`, `\r\n` or `System.Environment.NewLine` for line breaks in my C# applications?

I have a console, WinForms and WPF app which at present all use `\n` (where required), but in my console app I have found that when redirecting output from the CLi and open the output in Notepad the line breaks are not correctly recognised. I could just alter my behaviour for this one app but I am seeking the advice of those who consistently use a particular method and why.

Cheers!

Update:

So the general consensus is that use `System.Environment.NewLine` unless a specific requirement arises which needs `\n` (Unix/OS X), `\r` (OS 9) or `\r\n` (Windows)

Thanks all and sorry about the dup!

Comment: It depends on which platform do you plan to re-read your writes. However, unless specific requirements I would always go for Environment.NewLine

Comment: Good read about difference [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/newline),

Comment: @OndrejJanacek I did search both SO and Google, but must have somehow skimmed or just plain missed it; I cannot believe I missed something so bleeding obvious :(

Comment: @Steve cheers fro the succinct comment :)

Comment: @RohitVats that's a good explanation of a few different bits; cheers!

Comment: @SmithPlatts Sometimes I got an answer on my question in the moment I start writing a question here on SO and it shows me similar questions already asked.

Comment: @OndrejJanacek I have had that too before, but in this case not :/ (I always make a point to check the suggestions before even writing the question)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Better use [Environment.NewLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) because `\r` and `\n` are platform dependant.

> \n is Unix, \r is Mac, \r\n is Windows

`Environment.NewLine` would return any of the above based on the operating system.

Comment: Where "Mac" means Mac OS 9 or before .. [Mac] OS X is "Unix"

Comment: @user2864740 your little addendum to AccessDenied's answer is what got it marked as Answer; cheers both!

Answer (score 1):

It will always, unless you're intentionally writing a 'foreign' file, be best to use Environment.NewLine - that's what it's there for.  As you've discovered, sometime you can get away with other things, sometimes you can't.

It's very easy to write code which reads text files so that it doesn't really care what combination of \n and \r are used to end lines, but as you've discovered, Notepad is strict on this.

Comment: It all came from a complete ignorance where by I did not actually know about `NewLine` until today :/ (still somewhat newish to .NET from other languages); cheers for the answer!